# Poisson Process: Failures for a mechanical process where failures are major or minor and occur at different rates

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Failures occur for a mechanical process according to a Poisson process. Failures are classified as either major or minor. Major failures occur at the rate of 1.5 failures per hour. Minor failures occur at the rate of 3.0 failures per hour.

(c) Find the probability that in 2 hours, at least two major failures occur or at least two minor failures occur.

---

My initial intuition is that I want to find the union of at least two major, at least two minor. The problem is that I don't know how to get the intersection.

For the probability of minor being greater than 1 by time 2 I have:

$P(N_2 > 1) = 1 - (6e^{-6} + e^{-6}) = .98265$

And probability of major:

$P(N_2 > 1) = 1 - (3e^{-3} + e^{-3}) = .80085$

I hope this doesn't seem too wrong or that I had the right idea. Thank you in advance.

Edit: I tried superpositioning the two independentent Poisson processes.

This gave $P(N_2 > 1) = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-9}9^k}{k!} = 1- (9e^{-9} + e^{-9}) = .9988$$

This follows from the fact that $P(N_2 > 1) = 1- P(N_2 \le 1)$

This is super close to what the book has but is still off. My textbook claims the answer is .997

Edit 2: $N_2$ is the number of arrivals by time 2.

Comment: You used the random variable $N_2$ twice by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be the number of minor accidents and major accidents we observe, respectively.

If the two events are considered to be independent then

$$P(N_1\gt 1 \cap N_2 \gt 1)=P(N_1\gt 1)\cdot P(N_2 \gt 1)$$

Then since for two events $A$ and $B$, $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
P(N_1\gt 1 \cup N_2 \gt 1)
&=P(N_1\gt1)+P(N_2\gt1)-P(N_1\gt 1)\cdot P(N_2 \gt 1)\\\\
&=0.98265+0.80085-(0.98265\cdot0.80085)\\\\
&\approx 0.9965
\end{align*}$$

which agrees with your book's answer.

Comment: I think I should have written $N_2 > 1$ and $M_2 > 1$ because the number actually represents time 2. I added an edit clarifying. But thank you greatly for the answer. Based on my previous answers to parts (a) and (b) being correct I can safely assume that the book is treating these events as independent.